# I need a bit of lead with solving this fish detector problem by using a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

A fish-finder is a device used by anglers to find fish in a lake. If the fish-finder finds a fish, it will sound an alarm. It uses depth readings to determine whether to sound an alarm. For our purposes, the fish-finder will decide that a fish is swimming past if:

there are four consecutive depth readings which form a strictly increasing sequence (such as 3 4 7 9) (which we call "Fish Rising"), or
there are fur consecutive depth readings which form a strictly decreasing sequence (such as 9 6 5 2) (which we call "Fish Diving"), or
there are four consecutive depth readings which are identical (which we call "Constant Depth").
All other readings will be considered random noise or debris, which we call "No Fish."

Your task is to read a sequence of depth readings and determine if the alarm will sound.

**Sample Input**
The input will be four positive integers, representing the depth readings. each integer will be on its own line of input.

**Sample Output**
The output is one of four possibilities. If the depth readings are increasing, then the output should be Fish Rising. If the depth readings are decreasing, then the output should be Fish Diving. If the depth readings are identical, then the output should be Fish At Constant Depth. Otherwise, the output should be No Fish.

**Sample Input 1**
30
10
20
20
**Sample Output 1**
No Fish
**Sample Input 2**
1
10
12
13
**Sample Output 2**
Fish Rising

I've solved it normally but now I have to do it by using for loops and I have absolutely NO idea on how to even start. I have an example but it isn't helping.

```
num=int(input('Enter the number: '))
k = int(input('Enter the times the number has been shifted : '))

sum=0
sum+=num

for i in range(1,k+1):
  sum+=num*10**i

print(sum)
'for i in range(1,k+1):'
```

I solved this normally using elif and else statements but as for the for loop part, I don't even know where to begin from.
P.S: This is how I solved it.

```
d1, d2, d3 ,d4 = input("Enter first depth reading:"), input("Enter second depth reading:"), input("Enter third depth reading:"), input("Enter fourth depth reading:")

if int(d4) > int(d3) > int(d2) > int(d1):
    print("Fish Rising")
elif int(d1) > int(d2) > int(d3) > int(d4):
    print("Fish Diving")
elif int(d1) = int(d2) = int(d3) = int(d4):
    print("Constant Depth")
else:
    print("No Fish")
```

Comment: Can you share how you've solved this without using the for loop. We can likely help you adapt that into a loop.

Comment: This code has nothing to do with the task

Comment: Edit your question.  Do not put code in comments.

Comment: Okay I edited it and put my attempt to solve it (without for loop) in the question

Comment: Store the four numbers in a list.  You can use a for loop to subtract each one from the next one up. Now you have three differences.  Set a sum to 0.  For each difference, if the difference is positive, add 1.  If the difference is negative, subtract 1.   If 0, add 0. If the final result is 3, rising.  If -3, falling.  If 0, constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of the `for` loop is that you can handle an arbitrary number of fish.

```
def fishies( depths ):
    # This could be done easier with zip, but that's an advanced topic.
    ups = 0
    downs = 0
    for i in range(len(depths)-1):
        if depths[i] < depths[i+1]:
            ups += 1
        elif depths[i] > depths[i+1]:
            downs += 1

    if ups+downs == 0:
        return "Constant"
    elif ups == len(depths)-1:
        return "Diving"
    elif downs == len(depths)-1:
        return "Rising"
    return "No Fish"

print( fishies([3, 4, 7, 9]) )
print( fishies([9, 6, 5, 2, 1]) )
print( fishies([6, 6, 6, 6]) )
print( fishies([30, 10, 20, 20]) )
```